# Does keeping Windows 7 updated make anti-virus software useless?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, virus, anti-virus

I was thinking, given that I regularly keep Windows 7 updated through Windows Update,
doesn't this make having any anti-virus software useless. I may well be a naive user,
but it seems to me that if security concerns are found then any patches to the operating
system to close those security holes should solve the problem.

So, if my Windows 7 is up to date via Windows Updates, and I don't use an administrator account (a restricted account) do I still need an AntiVirus as surely I'd be protected.

Comment: In most cases AV companies identify and block exploits long before MS patches them. Also, AV helps blocks you from running infected things that may not use a flaw in Windows to infect you.

Comment: Can of Worms: Opened.

Comment: no. Windows updates often patch vulnerabilities used by Worms and Viruses, but rarely affect a Trojans ability to screw you over. Additionally lots of bad software can affect you and your user profile without administrative privileges. Back in '10, we were removing fake antivirus apps from systems where no admin had ever logged in.

Comment: Technically any virus software or windows update won't solve any trojan, virus, or maleware BEFORE it happens anyways. Kind of makes both seem unimportant. The best anti-maleware tool is to be careful where you click and such.

Comment: Why is this being voted to close? It's anything but opinion based, it's a good, useful question, with a very specific answer.

Comment: You've had many close votes, personally I think it's a good question so to *try* to keep it open, I've edited your post.

Comment: @dave - I was hoping that it wouldn't get closed either. Scott's answer is quite a good one and there is useful information in the thread. I Disagree with ramhounds assessment and his... somewhat snide comment towards me. I think I may of annoyed him in another question and he's been following me around critiquing me.

Comment: Don't worry @Arthur. Ramhound contributes a lot of his time here, the problem is he knows the rules well, and since you've only been here for just over 2 weeks, my advice is, ignore comments like that! Even if he did vote to close your post, was it closed? Remember, things on this site usually require a community to open/close etc. If he is leaving comments, it's probably his way of trying to help :)

Comment: OK, so I've posted what I thought was a reasonable question. I could reword my question, but I'm not sure how. I would be disappointed if this thread got deleted. Please give me some more input on what to do, whether to delete this thread, or, if it still needs rewording, then what exactly to reword. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson The Stack Exchange Network sites never delete a question unless it is blatantly a spam question, your question would just be closed, however it is easy to get a question reopened if it did get closed. If you want a place to get input on how to improve a question go to the http://meta.superuser.com site and ask a "meta" question about your closed question on how to improve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows updates will not protect you from software you yourself ran. If you are tricked in to running a malicious program it can unleash its payload.

[image]

You also state "if I keep myself logged in as a regular user without administrator privileges" but if you get a UAC prompt from a program and type in administrator credentials it does not matter that you where a regular user.

Windows updates also does not protect you from bugs in other software like your web browser (if not using IE), so a virus could get in that way which a anti-virus would have blocked.

Lastly, even if the program never gets administrative privileges and does not use any exploits in windows there is still plenty bad it can do as a restricted user, a non elevated program can read almost all the files on your hard drive and send that information anywhere it wants. If you contained any valuable information on your hard drive the writer of the virus now has a copy of that info.

Comment: Personally, besides using McAfee, if I think a program is going to behave as a trojan horse and mess up my computer, as a precaution I download and install that program inside a copy of Windows 7 running inside [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). That way, the program will mess up my guest machine, and I will likely notice that before proceeding to installing the potential software on my host computer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very opinion based so you are going to get a lot of different responses.

If you think that windows defender does a good enough job at defending against viruses? Then yes, You shouldn't have to worry about it.

Personally, I have problems with just windows defender. I find that it does not do a good enough job of catching threats before they strike. For my family, I use Mcafee.

Really, it boils down to your usage scenario. How often are programs downloaded? Is the computer mostly for internet or office use? does the user have administrative credentials? These are all things to consider before you decide what is the best way to secure the system.

Comment: "This question is very opinion based so you are going to get a lot of different responses." **means it should be closed not receive a bunch of different responses.**

Comment: ...then flag it.

Comment: I flagged it before I even submitted that comment.